# Flex text inserted into TextArea causes application to hang

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, textarea

I am attempting to insert text from a database into a custom TextArea component, using the following:

```
var front:CaptionTextArea = myFlashcardFrontsides[adjIndex] as CaptionTextArea;
var back:CaptionTextArea = myFlashcardBacksides[adjIndex] as CaptionTextArea;
var passage:CaptionTextInput = myVersePassages[adjIndex] as CaptionTextInput;
front.text = passage.text;
back.text = str;
```

This works 100% of the time for smaller strings.  However, if I insert long strings of text, the application will hang consistently.  The `maxchars` for the textarea is set to 1200, and the text that is inserted into the text area is always smaller than the character limit:

```
backside.maxChars = 1200;
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, and all I had to do was change my TextArea from a `Spark` TextArea to an `MX` TextArea:

```
//  import spark.components.TextArea; DON'T USE: SPARK TEXT AREA CAUSES A BUG WHEN PROGRAMATICALLY INSERTING LONGER TEXT STRINGS
import mx.controls.TextArea;

public class CaptionTextArea extends TextArea
```

It seems like there is an Adobe bug that causes my application to freeze when programatically inserting long strings of text into the newer text area.

Comment: Is there really an adobe bug?  Have you tried looking through the Spark TextArea code to find out what's the problem?  Can you find any other documentation of the bug on bugs.adobe.com?  Do you know that spark text uses TLF?  What kind of strings are you trying to set?  Seems a bit premature to just blame the SDK since I've used Spark text for quite a while without issue.

Comment: You're right, I haven't checked through the bugs repo for this particular issue, but I have run into other (documented) Spark bugs in the past, specifically with Spark text areas. I was probably venting some frustration with Adobe over the issue itself, but it is difficult to explain why inserting the same string would work using the MX Text Area but not Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue myself right now.
I think the problem is, when you add a long text (so long that scrollbars appear) to a TextArea and its not yet on the stage, the error is thrown. I believe the component has problems adding the scrollbar to the container.
mx:TextArea works, but its not good for styling the component, so it would be nice if apache (?) fixed that.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: this is just something i found out playing around with the TextArea